# which code is more efficient in bubble sorting in list (python)

Tags: python

```
myList = [8, 10, 6, 2, 4] # list to sort
i=4
while i>0:
    for j in range(i):
        if myList[j] > myList[j + 1]:
            myList[j], myList[j + 1] = myList[j + 1], myList[j]
    i-=1
print(myList)

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

myList = [8, 10, 6, 2, 4] # list to sort
swapped = True # it's a little fake - we need it to enter the while loop

while swapped:
    swapped = False # no swaps so far
    for i in range(len(myList) - 1):
        if myList[i] > myList[i + 1]:
            swapped = True # swap occured!
            myList[i], myList[i + 1] = myList[i + 1], myList[i]

print(myList)
```

Comment: They are both bad, and inefficient in their own ways.  The first one always compares every pair, the second will keep comparing already-sorted portions.

Comment: You can measure them yourself. Put each in a function and then use this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at both algorithms.
In the first one, we we go through the array fixed number of times. In the second we are iterating array until it is fully sorted.
If there would be a big array, the first algorithm will not sort array completely.
The second one will do it.
If the array is sorted initially, the first algorithm will iterate it three times - no mattering about it. The second will iterate one time.

**So, the second algorithm is better**

---

*A little post-scriptum*

*Because the task of sorting an array is quite usual, it is implemented as a built-in function. It is using [Trimsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which is better when bubble sort. Python has a good [tutorial about it](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Consider using it instead.*